# Retrofit JSON request not parsing the Java object

Tags: java, json, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

recently I had to make a JSON request to Pocket API for Modify endpoint. On their website, the encoded JSON array should be like this:
`https://getpocket.com/v3/send?actions=%5B%7B%22action%22%3A%22archive%22%2C%22time%22%3A1348853312%2C%22item_id%22%3A229279689%7D%5D&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&consumer_key=[CONSUMER_KEY]`

### First solution

I'm using Retrofit library, the method I wrote is this:

```
@Headers("X-Accept: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v3/send")
Call<ModifyItem> modify(@Field("actions[]") ArrayList<String> actions,
                        @Field("access_token") String token,
                        @Field("consumer_key") String consumerKey);

class ModifyItem {
    public ArrayList<Boolean> action_results;
    public int status;
}
```

And the JSON request produced in Logging Interceptor from OkHttp:
`actions%5B%5D=1689582274&actions%5B%5D=archive&actions%5B%5D=1505667307&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&consumer_key=[CONSUMER_KEY]`

### Second solution

As you can see the request is not the one I need. When I try to make it with POJO class, like it should be:

```
@Headers("X-Accept: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v3/send")
Call<ModifyItem> modify(@Field("actions[]") ArrayList<Action> actions,
                        @Field("access_token") String token,
                        @Field("consumer_key") String consumerKey);

class ModifyItem {
    public ArrayList<Boolean> action_results;
    public int status;
}
```

And the POJO class:

```
public class Action implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("action")
@Expose
private String action;
@SerializedName("item_id")
@Expose
private String itemId;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
private String time;

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
}
```

But the JSON request is this:
`actions%5B%5D=com.deyanm.pocketapispike.data.Action%4075efc7d1%5Baction%3Darchive%2CitemId%3D308680025%2Ctime%3D1505669208%5D&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&consumer_key=[CONSUMER_KEY]`

My question, is how I can achieve the desired JSON? Thanks

Comment: Hi deyanm, if this Pocket account is not just a demo account, you might want to remove the access token and the key from your question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, your `Action` class needs a proper `toString()` method.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{\"action\"=" + action +
           ",\"item_id\"=" + itemId +
           ",\"time\"=" + time + "}";
}
```

Second, the `actions` fields needs to be recognized as a single object, not a list of fields, so instead of using the ArrayList directly, use its toString() form

```java
Call<ModifyItem> modify(@Field("actions") String actions,
                        @Field("access_token") String token,
                        @Field("consumer_key") String consumerKey);
```

Then instead of `modify(actions, token, key)` use `modify(actions.toString(), token, key)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I slightly modified the toString method, to meet the desired requirements:
`@Override public String toString() { 
return "[{\"action\":\"" + action + 
"\",\"time\":" + time + 
",\"item_id\":" + itemId + 
"}]"; }`  
And everything worked as expected!